# ip versus dig/host, does ip provide DNS functionality?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system

Does the new `ip` alternative to `ifconfig` include functionality for DNS lookup like `dig` or `host`?

I have looked through the basic command list and do not see DNS-related commands.

Comment: A better question would include what specifically you use `dig` and such for, and how you want to improve that.

Comment: Please specify operating system in your question and/or tags. Platforms other than Linux exist.

Comment: "_does ip provide DNS functionality?_" IP only knows IP addresses. Names are used by applications, not the network stack. DNS is an application-layer protocol. The data-link, network, and transport layers know nothing about names.

Comment: @RonMaupin this is about `ip`, the tool and not about IP, the protocol.

Answer (score 5):

No, `ip` is not a robust DNS tool. All the `iproute` package does with names, per its man page, is optionally `-resolve` addresses. (Which the system resolver might not use DNS for.)